# How to have two vertical divs one next to the other, with the right one overflowing basing on the the other's height?

Tags: jquery, css, html, xhtml

I have two divs, these two divs must be arranged one next to the other. Basically the situation is the following:

```
<div>
   <div id="divl" style="width:25%;height:100%;float:left;clear:none">Sidemenu</div>
   <div id="divr" style="width:75%;height:100%;clear:none">Content</div>
</div>
```

Well, what I want to happen is the following. I can place them one next to the other but I have a problem. The right div should have its height depending on the left one. I mean that the right div's content should not cause the right div to have a hight higher than the left's one. Right div content is in overflow.

The total height should be ruled by the left div, the right one should adjust consequently.

That is it!. How to do this? Plain xhtml is possible? or do I need jQuery? Thanks

Comment: How you can have these side-by-side without using **floats**

Comment: I changed,, I forgot while typing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, this is easily achievable using jQuery:

**example markup**

```
  <div id="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="content">Page content here!</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$('#content').height($('#navigation').height());
```

**edit**

Make sure the above jQuery is put into the DOM ready function, otherwise the code will never be executed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#content').height($('#navigation').height());
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25b97/17/)

Comment: This does not work because my content div falls to height 0! Probably because it is not a dynamic calculated height...

Comment: What do you mean by it falls to 0? That example simply sets the height of `content` the same as the height of `navigation`

Comment: Ah... navigation... sorry I used the height of the other div... now it makes sense, trying it...

Comment: Have you given the `divs` the relevant `ids`, also see my edit

Comment: I do the following: `$('#divr').height($(`#divl`).height())` and as I told you `divr` disappears... I put this code just before closing `<body>`, so just before `</body>`...

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/) are some good methods, and their assorted [demos](http://css-tricks.com/examples/FluidEqualHeightFauxColumns/). This is an example taken from CSS-tricks:

```
<div id="one-true" class="group">
    <div class="col"><h3>I am listed first in source order.</h3><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p></div>
    <div class="col"><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p></div>
    <div class="col"><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p></div>
</div>

#one-true { overflow: hidden; }
#one-true .col {
    width: 27%;
    padding: 30px 3.15% 0; 
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
#one-true .col:nth-child(1) { margin-left: 33.3%; background: #ccc; }
#one-true .col:nth-child(2) { margin-left: -66.3%; background: #eee; }
#one-true .col:nth-child(3) { left: 0; background: #eee; }
#one-true p { margin-bottom: 30px; } /* Bottom padding on col is busy */
```

Comment: I am checking, please give me some time :)

Answer (score 0):

What if you simply controlled the height of the parent div? That would give the appearance of matching the hight of your two divs, by only controlled the height of the parent div.

http://jsfiddle.net/ccLBy/